# image is overflowing other div elements in css

Tags: html, css

I am learning CSS basics and don't understand this. Why image is larger than div class where he is at. Div class has specified width and height, but anyway image is much larger.

[Link to image example](http://gyazo.com/c122c60d4b73586158534bd249865ea8)

The html code is like this

```
<div id="logo"><a <%= link_to image_tag ('ecotechno_logo.png'), %></a> </div>
```

CSS for logo

```
#logo{
display: block;
padding:15px 0 0 30px;
float:left;
width: 268px;
height: 96px;
clear:both;
```

I am quite new in this, so any help will be appreciated
:) Thanks

Comment: `<a <%= link_to image_tag ('ecotechno_logo.png'), %>` what does it render ?

Comment: is  overflow: hidden what you want or scaling the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the html code

```
 <div id="logo"><%= link_to image_tag ('ecotechno_logo.png'), '#' %></div>
```

in css

```
#logo a img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width and height of the image as well.

something like:

```
#logo img { width:100px;height:100px; }
```

Feel free to change the '100px' to the size of the image that you want

Comment: Thanks, It worked, I will accept as answered after 8 minutes :)

Comment: But how can I assure right aspect ratio for image. because now it looks very creepy. It can be done using CSS or I have to create resized image and then just use .logo img {width:auto;height:auto;} ?

Comment: in regards to the div#logo size, you can set width:100%;height:100%; and just to be safe, you can also add display:block;

Answer (score 1):

Add your image url to an img tag of format:

```
<img src="" alt="" />
```

And you have to specify your width and height on the image not on the div. You can do this in css or on the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the image to get truncated, use

```
overflow: hidden
```

in the parent container.

If otherwise you want the image to get scaled to the container width use

```
#logo {width: 268px;}
#logo img { width: 100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Following code:

### HTML

```
<div id="logo"><a id="image" <%= link_to image_tag ('ecotechno_logo.png'), %></a> </div>
```

### CSS

```
#logo{
display: block;
float:left;
clear:both; }

#image{
margin:15px 0 0 30px;
width: 268px;
height: 96px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

set for div, in css, `overflow: hidden;` and width and height for image, in css or in img tag.